# What are Cooper pairs in superconductivity?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electrons, electrical-resistance, superconductivity, bosons

At low temperature how does electron become Cooper pair and why can they pass through a superconductor without resistance?
Please give quantum mechanical explaination.

Comment: Have you looked at the Wikipedia articles on [Cooper pairs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cooper_pair) and the [BCS theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BCS_theory)?

Comment: Related question by OP: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/437096/2451

Comment: Hi user210956. Welcome to Phys.SE. Please don't repost a question in a new entry. Instead, you are supposed to edit the original question within the original entry.